# Variadic Templates and Macros

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm currently working on an opengl wrapper,  but this code does not seem to be accepted by visual-c++:

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>
#include <GL/glew.h>

namespace Spiky {
namespace GLLayer {
template <typename RV, typename ... Params>
inline auto _checked_glFunc(
 RV (GLAPIENTRY *pfn)(Params...),
 const char*) -> decltype(pfn)
{
  return pfn;
}
template <typename RV, typename ...ARGS>
inline auto _checked_glFunc(RV (* GLAPIENTRY *ppfn)(ARGS...),
                            const char* func_name)
                          -> decltype(*ppfn)
{
  assert(!ppfn || !*ppfn, "Invalid GLFunction !");
  return *ppfn;
}

#define SPIKY_GLFUNC(FUNCNAME) \
::Spiky::GLLayer::_checked_glFunc(&::gl##FUNCNAME, ##FUNCNAME)

} //namespace GLLayer
} //namespace Spiky
```

main.cpp :

```
//includes..
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
  GLuint* names;
  SPIKY_GLFUNC(GenBuffers)(1, names); //gl call test
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Visualc++ actually gives me the error GenBuffers is undefined !

Any suggestions ?

***EDIT***

as pointed out, there was an error in the macro (see answer); but now I get this error : 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2784   'unknown-type Spiky::GLLayer::_checked_glFunc(RV (__cdecl **)(ARGS...),const char *)': could not deduce template argument for 'RV (__cdecl **)(ARGS...)' from 'PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC *'   SpikyEngine G:\Users\MattMatt\Workspace\Spiky-Git\spikyengine\source\src\main.cpp   83

Any suggestions ?

Comment: is there different overloads for `::glGenBuffers` ?

Comment: Well, according to the opengl specification, I don't think so... like you always pass in a different parameter, but it's a GLenum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're concatenating the bare token twice. Rather, you want the *stringification* the second time, which is done with the `#` operator:

```
#define SPIKY_GLFUNC(FUNCNAME) \
    ::Spiky::GLLayer::_checked_glFunc(&::gl##FUNCNAME, #FUNCNAME)
//                                                    ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks you :) But now I got this error :
Error C2784 'unknown-type Spiky::GLLayer::_checked_glFunc(RV (__cdecl **)(ARGS...),const char *)': could not deduce template argument for 'RV (__cdecl **)(ARGS...)' from 'PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC *

Comment: @Coder32: What happens when you remove the second overload, the one taking a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: it now gives me this error Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C2784 'unknown-type Spiky::GLLayer::_checked_glFunc(RV (__cdecl *)(Params...),const char *)': could not deduce template argument for 'RV (__cdecl *)(Params...)' from 'PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC *' SpikyEngine G:\Users\MattMatt\Workspace\Spiky-Git\spikyengine\source\src\main.cpp 233

Comment: PS : do you think it's a good idea to wrap opengl functions like this ? Do you have a better suggestion ?

Comment: @Coder32: I'm not sure what's going on. A [representative example](https://ideone.com/VEKPbe) works as intended for me. Maybe you can reduce your code to that or build it up from that.